# spring-boot 2.5.5 property "spring.config.import" not defined?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

after upgrade spring-boot:2.3.11.RELEASE to spring-boot:2.5.5 and spring-cloud:Hoxton.SR11 to spring-cloud:2020.0.4, spring-boot:run is failing with:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

No spring.config.import property has been defined

Action:

Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
    If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
    To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or 
    spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.
```

Advices are pretty clear so I added

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:
```

to both **application.properties** and **bootstrap.properties** files

In **application.properties** I had to comment out line `spring.config.import=optional:configserver:` otherwise it failed with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'optional:configserver:'  .........    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader`

As I didn't need to comment it out in **bootstrap.properties**, values are ignored completely there probably

However application itself failed the same way as without any new properties added.

Any ideas what is the problem? What is correct format for **spring.config.import=...** ?

EDIT:
after adding dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

it doesn't ignore properties in bootstrap.properties anymore so I had to comment out "spring.config.import=optional:configserver:" there as well. However application still failing with "No spring.config.import property has been defined"

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Cloud 2020 you dont need the `bootstrap.properties` file anymore, importing **spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap** enable only a legacy way to use it.
Just remove it...

You need to add

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://your.config.server.com
```

Into your `application.properties`. Howerver I am not sure what you are tring to achieve, because of your

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

[More Info](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)

Comment: Can you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899388/native-profile-is-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-7-0-for-calling-service?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

I'm using the version: **<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>**

In an **application.yaml** file, I added the following:

```
server:
port: 8761
eureka:
client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
spring:
cloud:
    config:
    enabled: false
application:
    name: eureka-server
```

**In the POM:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**I got the solution here:** https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

configuration

```
config:
  retry:
    initial-interval: 2000
    max-attempts: 10
  uri: http://localhost:8888
  fail-fast: false
```

and change application.yml to bootstrap.yml